# When and how to use DataSource instead of direct SqlConnection

Tags: c#, database, visual-studio, datasource

I'm trying to learn SQL and how to use it in my C# projects, but I'm struggling to understand how to connect it. So far I've seen most people simply do

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TestConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    /..
}
```

But in Visual Studio 2017, there is a tab for DataSource. Once I set my database connection there, I get a generated file *DbNameTest*, which I don't see to serve any purpose at all, there is no loaded data in it because I'm creating new instance of it every time I try to access it, I can save it, but I will still need to populate it the first time.

What's the point of using the DataSource tab and what's the purpose of the the DataSet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a profound subject that has many answers and methods. I'll try to explain it simply.

The datasource tab consists of ready-made structures presented to developers. With the help of the components in this tab, you can do many operations with dragging and dropping the code.

However, many developers prefer to build a more extensible and manageable structure by writing code instead of drag and drop with ready components.

DataSet; It is a copy of the database in ADO.NET. A dataset can contain one or more DataTables. DataTables are database tables.